# keep text in same position

Tags: html, css

I have a container-right in my html page in which there is a javascript slideshow and some text below.is there any attribute to keep the buttons and the text in same position even if the pictures have different sizes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried absolute positioning? but this way your text may be over the picture

Comment: What do you mean? Give some example.

Comment: You need to give us a simple piece of HTML code that shows us what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS use `poistion:fixed;` for the elements you want to fix

Comment: it overlaps the image with position:fixed;

Comment: Because you have changed the position type it will effect current values you have set for margin, these will need editing to get thew fixed element where you want it. Have you got a URL for the website?

Comment: Servant : i have image,with next,slideshow,stop buttons and some text below.when the image changes,the buttons and the text goes up or down.i have limited my image size and i want the buttons and text to stay in the same place

Comment: i have tried with position:fixed even if overlaps but still,when an image is smaller than the limit,the text and buttons go up

Comment: If you could paste your code somewhere i will take a look. Without a URL or the code it's very difficult to diagnose.